# Why doesn't @types/pdfjs-dist give Intellisense information in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js in in an Angular 7 webapp and I use VScode to edit the code. I have installed "pdfjs-dist": "^2.0.943" and "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.0.0".

I import pdf.js like this:

```
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf';
import * as pdfjsViewer from 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer';
```

Still all pdf.js funtions is shown as any by Intellisense. What am I doing wrong?